# How to duplicate Contentful content model

Tags: content-management-system, contentful

How to duplicate Contentful content model via https://github.com/contentful/contentful-migration? It can definitely be done via Web UI as shown below

[image: Duplicate button in UI]

Seems like there is no such an option in management API https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-management-api/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed it appears there is no single request that will duplicate a content model.

You would need instead to make two requests, first fetching the content model you want to duplicate, then creating the new model derived from it:

1. Fetch the source model:

   `GET /spaces/{space_id}/environments/{env_id}/content_types/{content_type_id}`
2. Prepare the request body to create the duplicate model: from the response to step 1, remove `sys` and update `name` to differentiate from the source model
3. Create the new model, using the request body from step 2:

   `PUT /spaces/{space_id}/environments/{env_id}/content_types/{new_content_type_id}`

Comment: Just be wary that any assets in the duplicate model won't be duplicated

Comment: Isn't the API for the 2nd request a `POST` to `content_types/`?

Comment: @psilocybin either `POST` or `PUT` can be used to create content types with the Contentful Management API, but [their documentation](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-management-api/#/reference/content-types) states "Whilst it's possible to create content types with `POST`, it's strongly discouraged."

Comment: @RWD Strange, doesn't seem very RESTful to be creating with a predefined ID and `PUT`